# Getting updated data from the server using promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used a promise and cached the response from the server. However, when I try to clear the cache and make a get request to the server again it keeps giving me the cached response. I know the task is being set to null in refresh task and the server is being called again but the response isn't changing. It is not until I reload the page that it will give me a new response.

factory list.js

```
app.factory('listService', function($http, $q, $cookies) {
//Create a class 
function listService() {

    var self = this;
    self.task = null;

    self.getTask = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      //If we already have the data, we can resolve the promise.
      if(self.task !== null) {
        console.log("cache");
        deferred.resolve(self.task);
      } else {
      //Get the data from the server.
          $http.get('http://dstm.herokuapp.com/api/tasks')
          .success(function(data) {
            self.task = data;
            console.log(self.task);
            console.log("server");
            deferred.resolve(data);
          })
          .error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            deferred.reject(response);
          });
    }

    //return the promise.
    return deferred.promise;

    };

    self.refreshTask = function(){
      self.task = null;
      console.log(self.task);
    }
 }

  return new listService();
});

app.controller('feedController', function($route, $scope, authFact, $location, $cookies, dataService, fileReader,listService) {

$scope.task = "";

$scope.newTask = function(){
    listService.getTask()
    .then(
    /* success function */
        function(data) {
            $scope.task = data;
        },
        /* error function */
        function(result) {
            console.log("Failed to get the name, result is " + result); 
    });
// $cookies.put('task', response.data);
// $scope.task = $cookies.get("task");
};

$scope.newTask();

$scope.refreshTask = function(){
    listService.refreshTask();
    $scope.newTask();

};
```

html

```
<button ng-click="refreshTask()" id="newTask" type="button">New Task</button>
```

Comment: What does your browser Network tab tell ? Dies it say getting an actual request with 200 and does the response data matches your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete that item from the `$httpDefaultCache`, like so:

```
$scope.refreshTask = function(){
    // update controller to inject $httpDefaultCache
    $httpDefaultCache.removeAll(); 
    listService.refreshTask();
    $scope.newTask();
};
```

You can also call `$httpDefaultCache.remove('http://someurl.com/a/b/c')` to remove a single item by its URL.

For more info, check out the docs on the `$cacheFactory`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$cacheFactory